# Apache Beam Flatten is not taking data from others Pcollection

Tags: java, apache-beam

This is my pic of code.I am trying to merge data from one PCollection to others PCollection.Although In graph view of dataflow it is showing but data is not coming

PCollectionList<List> collections = PCollectionList.of(finalPayload).and(opPCol);

PCollection<List> mergedPcoll = collections.apply(Flatten.<List>pCollections());

Comment: does it show if you print only `collections` ?

Comment: Are you sure `finalPayload` and `opPCol` are not both empty?

Comment: Yes,@robertwb, not empty

Comment: Can you try counting the number of elements in finalPayload, opPCol, and mergedPcoll.

Comment: I think you should check the official documentation about [designing pipelines](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/design-your-pipeline/) which cover handling many pCollections and how you can merge it. Also, I invite you to check the official github project page for apache beam [join examples](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/cookbook/JoinExamples.java). It would be helpful if you can also provide additional details such as opPCol definition and finalPayload details. As well as input and output mockup-data.