# apache beam Flatten in Java , The Data is not flowing to next level

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

some how the pcollection of data from previous step is not flowing to next level -

Below is the code

```
PCollection finalPayload = daCheck.apply(
     "Read Alarm data from Redies",
     ParDo.of(new BigQueryProcessor.RediesFinalPayload(redisInstance))
        //.withOutputTags(
            CommonUtil.SUZLONINOX_ALARM,
            TupleTagList.of(CommonUtil.NORMAL_ALARM))
        .withSideInputs(bq_row)
    );
    
PCollectionList<List<MicroServiceResponse>> collections = 
    PCollectionList.of(finalPayload).and(opPCol);
    
PCollection<List<MicroServiceResponse>> mergedPcoll = 
    collections.apply(
        Flatten.<List<MicroServiceResponse>>pCollections());
    
PCollection<List<MicroServiceResponse>> opPCol = 
    normalAlarmPCol.apply(
        "Binary Conversion",
        ParDo.of(
            new DoFn<KV<Neo4jResponse, List<MicroServiceResponse>>, List<MicroServiceResponse>>() {
                @ProcessElement
                public void process(ProcessContext c){ 
                    // logic 
                }
             }));
```

Comment: which stages are not receiving data from the previous level ?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71586061/apache-beam-flatten-is-not-taking-data-from-others-pcollection ?

Comment: @robertwb  yes its same

Comment: @ewertonvsilva  below stage is not taking data from previous stage

Comment: May I ask, what are you trying to achieve? Also what is your output collection? (based on the code it looks like `mergedPcoll` ). Before using `Flatten` up to that point `collections` have any records? . I suggest you to check [the java beam cookbook samples](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/cookbook) and Merging PCollections topic on [apache beam design your pipeline](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/design-your-pipeline/).